# UIButton title hides on click of it

Tags: objective-c

I have created a UIButton onject programmatically with a background image set to it. Its initial state is UIControlStateNormal.But when I click the button its title gets hidden and when I click and hold the button its title is visible in highlighted state.
I have tried multiple combinations of various control states and events.But each time the title gets hidden.
I am not getting what the problem is!!
Please help.

Comment: You can also change the title's color for each state, does that help? Perhaps the button title's color for the state "UIControlStateSelected" blends in with the background image?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what I think you want (a constant title on the button, regardless of control state) by setting one title for both control states:

```
NSString *titleString = @"Hello World";
[aButton setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

You may also wish to toggle the color of the title on highlight, if your title text color isn't contrasted sufficiently against your highlighted background:

```
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//OR
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If it's your image giving you trouble, what you might want to simply disable image adjustment for highlighting:

```
[aButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
```